# PHP script with mysqli_query inserting twice in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I have a webpage with Wordpress, working fine, we're currently updating our PHP scripts to use MySQLi instead of MySQL instructions. The problem is, the mysqli_query statement is inserting twice the same row.

We have a page that calls a PHP script which contains a form that, once completed and submitted, inserts the result in the database. With MySQL worked right, but with MySQLi, it inserts twice. Any clues on how to solve this? I've tried all I know. This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Confirma'])){
    include ('Conexion1.php');
    $fechainsert = date("Y-m-d");
    $nombre      = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $password    = $_POST['Password'];
    $email       = $_POST['Email'];
    ...
    $observacion = $_POST['Observacion'];
    $sql="INSERT ignore INTO Coche (Usuario,Password,Email, Telefono, Caducidad, Categorias, Precio,Otros,Circuito, Asfalto, Tierra, RCross, Raids, Marca, Modelo, Preparacion, Fabricacion, Observaciones, Insercion) VALUES ('$nombre','$password','$email','$telefono','$caducidad','$tipo','$precio','$Otros','$Circuito','$Asfalto','$Tierra','$Cross','$Raids','$marca','$modelo','$preparacion','$fabricacion','$observacion','$fechainsert')";
    $connect->query($sql);
    $connect->close();
}?>
```

This is the connection file:
Conexion1.php

```
<?php
$connect   = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo '<p>La conexión al servidor MySQL ha fallado: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . '</p>';
}
?>
```

I've isolated the code on local, and it works flawlessly. The problem has something to do with mixing Wordpress and MySQLi.

Comment: Why are you manually writing out those queries instead of just using WP's query methods?
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

Comment: This method will work with the already existing tables?

Comment: Yes. I've done it many times. Including with custom tables. There's lots of reference material out there for it.

Comment: I tried it, and it seems that my tables aren't in the WP database. I tried using wpdb to connect to my database instead of mysqli, and it redirects me to the wordpress's database.

Comment: So you're accessing an entirely different database than the Wordpress database? Why would you be inserting user info in to different database from within Wordpress? That sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: They are ads, which are stored in that external database, not user info. I don't know, I was given the website to work with and they do it that way. But do you have any clue on what the problem may be?